# R- Insert rows of another dataframe after every row of dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe: mydata1 and mydata2, both 222x80.
I want to create a new dataframe in which after every row of mydata1 I add the row (same index) of mydata2.
I tried with transform function, but the output is duplicating the rows of the same dataframe.
I can't substitute all columns values.
If someone has suggestion, Thank you!!

```
insert.mydataFeat <- transform(mydata1, colnames(mydata1)=colnames(mydata2))
out.mydataFeat <- rbind(mydata1, insert.mydataFeat)
#reorder the rows
n <- nrow(mydata1)
out.mydataFeat<-out.mydataFeat[kronecker(1:n, c(0, n), "+"), ]
out.mydataFeat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing trick after combining the data with `rbind`.

```
mydata1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 'A')
mydata2 <- data.frame(col1 = 6:10, col2 = 'B')

combine_df <- rbind(mydata1, mydata2)
combine_df <- combine_df[rbind(1:(nrow(combine_df)/2), 
                ((nrow(combine_df)/2) +1):nrow(combine_df)), ]

#   col1 col2
#1     1    A
#6     6    B
#2     2    A
#7     7    B
#3     3    A
#8     8    B
#4     4    A
#9     9    B
#5     5    A
#10   10    B
```

where

```
rbind(1:(nrow(combine_df)/2), ((nrow(combine_df)/2) +1):nrow(combine_df))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

the above creates a two row matrix with 1st row as row numbers from 1st dataframe and 2nd row as row numbers from second dataframe and we use that to subset `combine_df`.